# Data on Private Ethereum blockchain lost/disappears after couple of days

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

I am deploying a private ethereum blockchain (geth) on a virtual machine on Azure. Upon deploying my Solidity contracts on the blockchain and launching my NodeJS application to it, I am able to add data normally through web apis of the nodejs Loopback App and everything is working fine and I can see the added data using the GET apis.

However, after 1-2-3 days (random) I am not able to retrieve the data I added through my GET apis, while am still able to add new data which confirms that Geth is running fine and wasn't interrupted.

I am running geth using:

```
geth --datadir ./myDataDir --rpc --networkid 1441 console 2>> myEth.log
```

myEth.log isn't showing anything wrong, nodejs logs are clean as well.

`eth.syncing` shows `false` which means the network is synced.

size of `myDataDir` folder is still increasing so logically data should be somewhere there but it's not showing.

Comment: Is it possible that some required login expires after 1-3 days?

Comment: No definitely not @David, there's no such login process to talk to it, and if there's any it's already working since the beginning and there's no expiry date for it.

Comment: mhm, did you miss perhaps an included expiry-parameter?
I don't think so, but I don't know that blockchain so I don't know the unique details. Alternative: perhaps you send a delete-command without recognizing it?

Comment: I dont think so as well, because sometimes it's the data is kept in blockchain for a week or more. it's definitely related to transactions cost and ethereum configuration, am afraid it's a bug in 1.8.6 version! I'm contacting consensys support to see if they can help!

Comment: yeah, sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1):

This is not a private blockchain!

```
--networkid 1441
```

This only says that you communicate with clients that also run a network with ID 1441. It might be unlikely, but if someone else runs a network with ID 1441, this node will connect to your node just fine. And in case, the other network with the same ID has a longer (more "heavier") chain, this overwrites your local chain.

To avoid this, try a more random network ID, maybe 7-9 digits, and disable discovery with

```
 --nodiscovery
```

Or just use the `--dev` preset.